# Flutter - How to add Multipi API data source?

Tags: api, flutter

I have 2 API with the same data but different link, Sometime one of them isn't working so I want to try to get data from first one if it's not working so get data from the second (**as a backup data source** )

Can any one help me to do this ?
Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class MyWorking {
  Future getData() async {
    String data;
    Response response = await get(
        'first Url');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = response.body;
      print(data);
      return jsonDecode(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to call your other API in your `else condition`, and you're done. What is the issue in doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked but as you can see the second url in if statement so is their away to but it under the first url ?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class MyWorking {
  Future getData() async {
    String data;
    Response response = await get('first URL');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = response.body;
      return jsonDecode(data);
    } else if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      response = await get('second URL');
      data = response.body;
      return jsonDecode(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
Future getData(int index) async { //changed this line
  List<String> data = ['first url','second url']; //changed this line
  
  Response response = await get(data[index]);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    data = response.body;
    print(data);
    return jsonDecode(data);
  } else {
    print(response.statusCode);
    
    index == 0 ? getData(1):getData(0); //add this line
    
  }
}
```